# How to Inflate XML layout in RelativeLayout class in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

create RelativeLayout class in my View package
and Inflate XML file in class 
for use into main activity
but without any Error, emulator has stopped

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import net.sibdiet.R;

public class AboutView extends RelativeLayout {

    private TextView about_txt;
    private AssetManager assets;

    public AboutView(Context context) {
        super( context );
        initializeViews( context );
    }

    public AboutView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super( context, attrs );
        initializeViews( context );
    }

    private void initializeViews(Context context) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.aboutus_layout, this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
        about_txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.aboutus_txt);
    }

    public AssetManager getAssets() {
        return assets;
    }
}
```

i need inflate aboutus_layout.xml

```
<merge
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/aboutus_txt"
            android:layout_width="61dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/about"
            android:textColor="@color/Green"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</merge>
```

use custom view in main activity
main_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#DCDCDC"
    tools:context="net.sibdiet.MainActivity">

    <net.sibdiet.View.AboutView
        android:id="@+id/about_us_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

blahYour post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems of your code are:

1) Replace `LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);` with `LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext())`

2) Remove `RelativeLayout` from your aboutus_layout.xml because it's excess there.  makes your view (AboutView) be at the root of the view hierarchy.